# People Search "My Colleague" attribute overlap email address in Search Result

Tags: enterprise-search, people-search

We have SharePoint 2010 search ceter and when users do a people search and the person is a coleague, the **My Colleague" attribute** ovelatop their email address in the search results (as shown below). Is there a way to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Use firebug to find the classname/div name and add margin-top, display: block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a css problem and not a search problem. You can adjust the css/styles with Firebug/Chrome/Developer Tools as Yas72 suggested.

You can post the css styles in an update of your question to get further help.